# Understanding 9,000 views in 4 days on question?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

This [GPS vs NAVIC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191520/gps-vs-navic-the-indian-navigation-system) question received almost 9000 views in the 4 days since it was asked. 
On average, 4 day old questions have about 30 views, with other high view question gaining just over 100 views.

This doesn't seem right. The user is from India, with 1.25 billion people and ~450 million internet users, which may have something to do with it.

What do you think?

Comment: Even if there was anything wrong, what exactly do you think we should do about it?

Comment: Little help here. Still trying to figure out why a bunch of views on a closed question is a problem . . .

Comment: The closing of the question is not the topic of the question, the unusually high view count is

Comment: I know. I mean what's the big deal? It might have been concerning if there were a bunch of wrong answers getting unjustifiably upvoted, but the only problem here is a number, which isn't a problem IMO.

Comment: Could you please clarify how the user's location may influence the number of views?

Comment: @Aaron India's population is 1.25 Billion, with ~450 Million internet users

Comment: Thanks @HDunn, I edited your question with your comments to clarify.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question was prompted by recent news:

- [India get its own GPS system NAVIC](http://tech.economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/technology/india-get-its-own-gps-system-navic/52035101)
- [IRNSS Is Now Navic: India's Navigation System Gets a Simpler Name](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/science/news/irnss-is-now-navic-indias-navigation-system-gets-a-simpler-name-831398)
- [The desi GPS: ISRO’s seventh satellite NAVIC completes the system](http://www.hindustantimes.com/india/the-desi-gps-isro-s-seventh-satellite-navic-completes-the-system/story-ZDaQTtP187epUOCwpFEgwL.html)
- ....

Since Stack Exchange sites are generally highly ranked by search engines, people who wanted to know about the new system, in particular its differences from familiar GPS, were led to the question.

I guess they left disappointed.

Comment: That actually makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening us with this information. I reopened the question after a user provided a valuable edit.

Comment: It's a shame that none of that background nor a focussed question (to attract quality answers) was posted within the question on Main to capitalize on the additional traffic

Comment: It might be worth keeping an eye out for unanswered questions that are getting a lot of views per day.